# Gradle clean build - build kicks off prior to clean completing

Tags: windows, gradle

I have a multi project Gradle build script that runs successfully on Windows 10.  It reads and updates a Version.properties file that is located away from project managed directories. 
 All file manipulations are done using Gradle/groovy.  After the Version file has been read, incremented and rewritten it is copied to a build/classes directory where it will be picked up by subsequent jar and shadowjar tasks.
Everything works as advertised if I invoke gradle as follows:

```
gradle build shadowjar ... etc.
```

However, if I invoke the clean task prior to build the file is read and incremented properly but the copy of the file fails silently.

The command used is:

```
gradle clean build shadowjar
```

My suspicion is that gradle does not wait for the clean task to finish prior to starting the build task.  The file gets read and incremented but meanwhile, the multi-project clean activities have not yet finished.  I have tried variations on dependencies{} blocks, doFirst{} and doLast{} to try and push the file copy back further in the build process.  My main requirement is to have the Version.properties file in place prior to the jar or shadowjar task executing.  I'm suspicious of trying to write into gradle's build/ directories in that it might not be possible to put anything into the build directories while gradle is performing its activities.  Is there any way to ensure that the Version.properties file (or any generated file) gets copied? Or is there another location that I can use that will not be blown away by gradle at clean time yet still get picked up in the build:jar / build:shadowjar?

Comment: Are you using parallel execution (`--parallel` or `org.gradle.parallel=true`)?

Which version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: gradle -version returns Gradle 3.3 with Groovy 2.4.7.  I have not enabled --parallel anywhere in my build.gradle scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to call gradle clean 99.99% of the time, it is redundant due to gradle's incremental build feature. So as long as you correctly define your task inputs and outputs and start from ground up in each task, the problem solves itself.

Anyway in your case the wrong order could be caused by dependency between clean and other tasks, is there any?

Comment: clean and build have not been modified in anyway that would cause one to start out of other with default gradle behavior.  I believe the answer that I have posted is the correct one:  Don't mess with gradle build directories in a task (even the gradle build task itself - which is where my version file increment/copy is called from).  By setting the destination of the copy to a different location, the problem disappears and the copy succeeds.  The reason that clean is called prior to build is to ensure that no old code or test executions are laying around in the build location.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to write out a generated Version.properties file that will get picked up by the jar and shadowjar tasks. Use the gradle copy task and place the revised Version.properties file into a resources directory. The build activity includes the files found in resources/ in subsequent tasks (jar, shadowjar, test, etc.) My suspicion is that because clean blows away build directories gradle assumes that the activity has fully completed when it starts the build. I think that I've proven that this is not the case. doFirst{}, doLast{} and dependencies{} do not seem to work as modifiers to clean build.